# A set of rotated/reflected L-shapes

Tags: knowledge, visual, pattern

What does the image below represent? Explain your reasoning.

---

[image]

Comment: Note: Added knowledge-tag. Relying on external sources is not really necessary but will most likely be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This image represents

> The 22 times in a 12 hour period that an analog clock's hands are at right angles!

This is seen if

> we treat the short and long segments of the L's as hour and minute hands. The first clock shows a bit after 12:15 and each clock thereafter shows the next time (close to a half hour later) the hands are again at right angles.
>  For the math behind it, see [right angles of a clock](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77299/right-angles-in-the-clock-during-a-day).

Comment: Yup this is it. NIce job!